# How can I align my points/models rotation along the model surface

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes, and trying to align my instance geometry around a sphere, however my geometry is not rotating along the surface of the sphere. The geometry is sticking straight up. I know I can add rotation point to make them randomly rotate, however I want the geometry to align the same way the current point is sitting on the face of the sphere is. I tried using an "align rotation to vector" but no luck there.

Edit:
Here is an image of a test set up:

[image: geometry node setup] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUlB1.png "geometry node"

[image: rendered view of failed geometry node]

Here is the blend file a basic setup with non working align rotation geometry nodes

https://www.mediafire.com/file/meai3z5j9z9m4av/Basic_Geometry_Node_Align_Not_Working.blend/file

Double edit: I missed that the the align rotation needed to be set all to 0. It's working  beautifully now. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: show us your node tree or your blend file

Answer (score 3):

1. add a sphere and a cone to your scene.
2. add geometry node tree to your sphere
3. add this node tree:

[image]

4. adjust size of cone in edit mode

result

[image]

Comment: _No Comprendo_ :) .. Is your _Align to Vector_  (0,0,0) doing anything?

Comment: believe it or not - with this setup the vector doesn't care at all...

Comment: the joke is...it works only with point distribute node. If you mute it - it won't work. I guess it is a bug...

Comment: The 'Vector' in _Align Rotation to Vector_ is a direction, not a point in space. (The direction _from_ 0,0,0 _to_ the value you enter,  in object space) So I was remarking on your zero-length value of (0,0,0), which, here,  is not a direction at all. As far as I can see,  if 0,  Blender just ignores it, reverting to the default rotation, normal to the surface. In this context, I see no bug. Points have a `rotation` attribute, manipulated by this node. If instanced, that attribute appears in the 'Instances' page of the spreadsheet.